# Rake db:migrate error "don't know how to build task"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, sqlite

I've got a table where I used integer on a field which needs decimal places, so I'm trying to create a migration which changes the field type from integer to float/real. My database is sqllite3 and I'm using rails3.

I ran

```
rails generate migration ChangeMeasureColumnOnIngredients
```

to create the initial migration files, then updated the  class to

```
class ChangeMeasureColumnOnIngredients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :ingredients, :measure, :real
  end
```

I ran rake db:migrate and it returned fine.

When I inserted a value via my rails app, it didn't return the decimal place. I started to think that many rails doesn't know what 'real' is as a datatype, so I changed the migration to

```
change_column :ingredients, :measure, :float
```

I then ran

```
rake db:migrate change_measure_column_on_ingredients
```

and now I get the following error

```
c:\Ruby192\rails3rc>rake db:migrate change_measure_column_on_ingredients
(in c:/Ruby192/rails3rc)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'change_measure_column_on_ingredients'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1720:in []'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2040:ininvoke_task'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:ineach'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in block in top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:instandard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:inrun'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:31:in `'
```

I tried changing the :float back to :real, but I still get that error.

can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
I'm new to rails and still learning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your rake call has instructed rake to build the task `db:migrate` followed by the task `change_measure_column_on_ingredients` which clearly isn't want you want as the latter is not a rake task.

To run a specific migration you need to provide the `VERSION` of the migration. This is the number in the file name which comes before your name for the migration. You can migrate it up or down like this:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=123456789
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=123456789
```

Alternatively you can take the last migration down then up by doing the following (you can also specify a `VERSION` for this):

```
rake db:migrate:redo
```

There are other options though. If you run `rake --describe db:migrate` you'll get some more information.

Answer (score 0):

While in this specific instance the stacktrace posted by OP shows the error is trying to do two tasks at once, I found this page after googling and just want to add to the answer for future googlers:

try including either `RAILS_ENV=development` or `RAILS_ENV=test` as that is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score -4):

make sure your command is  `rake db:migrate` . Pay attention to there is no any space between `:` and `migrate`