# Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate' w/ Rails 3.2.0.rc2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm attempting to upgrade my Rails application to 3.2.0.rc2 but When I try to do a `rake db:migrate --trace` I'm now getting the following error message:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionController::Base instead. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/application.rb:4)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

The deprecation warning seems to be in regards to this line in `application.rb`:

```
Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

Is this supposed to be removed or changed in the latest version of Rails? I tried removing this line, and running the migrate again. I then no longer get the warning but still get the `Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'` error. Any ideas?

Doing a `bundle exec rake -T` yields the following:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionController::Base instead. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/application.rb:4)
rake about                               # List versions of all Rails frameworks and the environment
rake assets:clean                        # Remove compiled assets
rake assets:precompile                   # Compile all the assets named in config.assets.precompile
rake cron                                # This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on
rake doc:app                             # Generate docs for the app -- also available doc:rails, doc:guides, doc:plugins (options: TEMPLATE=/...
rake friendlyid:rebuild                  # Updates all User and Skatepark friendly IDs
rake geocode:all                         # Geocode all objects without coordinates.
rake jobs:work                           # Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)
rake log:clear                           # Truncates all *.log files in log/ to zero bytes
rake middleware                          # Prints out your Rack middleware stack
rake notes                               # Enumerate all annotations (use notes:optimize, :fixme, :todo for focus)
rake notes:custom                        # Enumerate a custom annotation, specify with ANNOTATION=CUSTOM
rake rails:template                      # Applies the template supplied by LOCATION=(/path/to/template) or URL
rake rails:update                        # Update configs and some other initially generated files (or use just update:configs, update:scripts...
rake resque:scheduler                    # Start Resque Scheduler
rake resque:work                         # Start a Resque worker
rake resque:workers                      # Start multiple Resque workers.
rake routes                              # Print out all defined routes in match order, with names.
rake secret                              # Generate a cryptographically secure secret key (this is typically used to generate a secret for coo...
rake sorcery:bootstrap                   # Adds sorcery's initializer file
rake spec                                # Run all specs in spec directory (excluding plugin specs)
rake spec:controllers                    # Run the code examples in spec/controllers
rake spec:helpers                        # Run the code examples in spec/helpers
rake spec:lib                            # Run the code examples in spec/lib
rake spec:mailers                        # Run the code examples in spec/mailers
rake spec:models                         # Run the code examples in spec/models
rake spec:rcov                           # Run all specs with rcov
rake spec:requests                       # Run the code examples in spec/requests
rake spec:routing                        # Run the code examples in spec/routing
rake spec:views                          # Run the code examples in spec/views
rake stats                               # Report code statistics (KLOCs, etc) from the application
rake sunspot:reindex[batch_size,models]  # Reindex all solr models that are located in your application's models directory.
rake sunspot:solr:run                    # Run the Solr instance in the foreground
rake sunspot:solr:start                  # Start the Solr instance
rake sunspot:solr:stop                   # Stop the Solr instance
rake test                                # Runs test:units, test:functionals, test:integration together (also available: test:benchmark, test:...
rake test:recent                         # Run tests for {:recent=>"test:prepare"} / Test recent changes
rake test:single                         # Run tests for {:single=>"test:prepare"}
rake test:uncommitted                    # Run tests for {:uncommitted=>"test:prepare"} / Test changes since last checkin (only Subversion and...
rake time:zones:all                      # Displays all time zones, also available: time:zones:us, time:zones:local -- filter with OFFSET para...
rake tmp:clear                           # Clear session, cache, and socket files from tmp/ (narrow w/ tmp:sessions:clear, tmp:cache:clear, tm...
rake tmp:create                          # Creates tmp directories for sessions, cache, sockets, and pids
```

It would appear as if all of my `rake db` tasks are missing.

Comment: what does bundle exec rake -T say?

Comment: Updated my question w/ the output. It appears all of the `rake db` tasks are missing.

Comment: Do you do a `require 'rails/all'` in your application.rb or are you loading a subset?

Comment: I'm requiring `rails/all`. Feel free to take a look at my project at https://github.com/skateparks/skateparks-web

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is something very funky going on with your gem versions. If you look at your gemfile.lock it's using the 3.2.rc2 versions of railties, activesupport and activemodel but the other versions are all over the place ( ar is 1.6, action mailer is 0.6.1 etc).

I'm not sure how you got into this state, but I'd try either `bundle update` or deleting Gemfile.lock and then running `bundle install` (in theory those 2 are equivalent) and specifying the precise version of rails you want (especially as you're after a prerelease version of rails.)

Comment: This appears to be happening because I'm not explicitly specifying `3.2.0.rc2` in my Gemfile. I assumed that just putting `gem rails` would be sufficient but I guess not. Could this be a bug w/ Rails?

Comment: If it's a bug in anything it would be in bundler. That said strictly speaking the set of gems that have been selected do match your gemfile (possibly because some of the older versions were more relaxed about the versions specified)

Comment: Deleting Gemfile.lock + bundle install worked perfect. Cheers.

Comment: hi Giles, i did the same (Deleting Gemfile.lock + bundle install ) but did not work for me :(

Answer (score 5):

From the command `rake db:migrate --trace`, the rake tasks are not loaded. , amd you couldn't get the path scheme right.
and running `rake -T` locally list `db:migrate` as one of the rake tasks? If 
not, your rails is misconfigured...
well, I didn't worked with rails 3.2.0rc2 ,but I googled and found some links .
Please refer links below this would help you..

[Rake db:migrate error don't know how to build task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671061/rake-dbmigrate-error-dont-know-how-to-build-task)

[Don't know how to build rake db:migrate on Ubuntu natty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002992/dont-know-how-to-build-rake-dbmigrate-on-ubuntu-natty)

[Problem running rake db:migrate](http://wrath.rubyonrails.org/pipermail/rails/2006-July/056282.html)

Let me know how it worked !

Thanks Frederick, Its interesting post..