# Syntax error and db.migrate error preventing me from moving forward

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

https://github.com/justuseapen/omrails

Link to the repo^

When I run the app on my local server I get a syntax error in the browser. Apparently something wrong with the `<%= end %>` in my application.html.erb file.

I followed the onemonthrails tut as exactly as possible, excluding the heroku pushes because I cannot for the life of me get my ssh keys to line up (that's for another question).

Also, when I run `rake db:migrate` (or `bundle exec db.migrate`) I get an error that says

```
don't know how to build task db.migrate
```

Any suggestions on a fix? I already check this question: [Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate' w/ Rails 3.2.0.rc2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871368/dont-know-how-to-build-task-dbmigrate-w-rails-3-2-0-rc2)

and found no relevant solution but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: can you show the full text of the error and the code that it's referencing?

Comment: Did you mean `bundle exec rake db:migrate` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more specifics, it might be that `<%= end %>` should be written as `<% end %>` (no `=`) is the trouble with your `application.html.erb`

Also, `bundle exec db.migrate` should be `bundle exec db:migrate` (`:` rather than `.`)

Comment: Thank you for the syntax correction I don't know why the = is required for every other line but not the end. Thanks for that. Regarding the db:migrate error:

I corrected the syntax (: not .) but then I get bundler command not found db:migrate.

Comment: Oh my goodness I forgot to put rake before db:migrate! Thank you so much for your help. What a silly mistake.