# Can not execute commands like "rails db:*"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am currently writing a website with Ruby on rails for a few months.

Suddenly (5 or 6 days ago), all the commands like `rails db:migrate`, `rails db:rollback`, `rails db:*`" don't work anymore (and it does not seem to have touched anything...).

I tried to reinstall the gems `rake`, `rails` and `railsties` (which were already in their latest versions) but the problem still persists.

[My Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/aurelebonvin/5c694264fa323b94bdb453ff6b2926d0)

The result when I execute the command `rails db:migrate`:

```
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The result when I execute the command `rake db:migrate`:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The result when I execute the command `rails --tasks --all`:

```
rails app:template                       # Applies the template supplied by LOCATION=(/path/t...
rails app:templates:copy                 #
rails app:update                         # Update configs and some other initially generated ...
rails app:update:bin                     #
rails app:update:configs                 #
rails app:update:upgrade_guide_info      #
rails assets:clean[keep]                 # Remove old compiled assets
rails assets:clobber                     # Remove compiled assets
rails assets:environment                 # Load asset compile environment
rails assets:precompile                  # Compile all the assets named in config.assets.prec...
rails autoprefixer:info                  # Show selected browsers and prefixed CSS properties...
rails cache_digests:dependencies         # Lookup first-level dependencies for TEMPLATE (like...
rails cache_digests:nested_dependencies  # Lookup nested dependencies for TEMPLATE (like mess...
rails default                            #
rails dev:cache                          # Toggle development mode caching on/off
rails environment                        #
rails initializers                       # Print out all defined initializers in the order th...
rails log:clear                          # Truncates all/specified *.log files in log/ to zer...
rails middleware                         # Prints out your Rack middleware stack
rails notes                              # Enumerate all annotations (use notes:optimize, :fi...
rails notes:custom                       # Enumerate a custom annotation, specify with ANNOTA...
rails notes:fixme                        #
rails notes:optimize                     #
rails notes:todo                         #
rails restart                            # Restart app by touching tmp/restart.txt
rails routes                             # Print out all defined routes in match order, with ...
rails secret                             # Generate a cryptographically secure secret key (th...
rails stats                              # Report code statistics (KLOCs, etc) from the appli...
rails test                               # Runs all tests in test folder except system ones
rails test:controllers                   #
rails test:db                            # Run tests quickly, but also reset db
rails test:functionals                   #
rails test:generators                    #
rails test:helpers                       #
rails test:integration                   #
rails test:jobs                          #
rails test:mailers                       #
rails test:models                        #
rails test:prepare                       #
rails test:run                           #
rails test:system                        # Run system tests only
rails test:units                         #
rails time:zones[country_or_offset]      # List all time zones, list by two-letter country co...
rails time:zones:all                     #
rails time:zones:local                   #
rails time:zones:us                      #
rails tmp                                #
rails tmp/cache                          #
rails tmp/cache/assets                   #
rails tmp/pids                           #
rails tmp/sockets                        #
rails tmp:cache:clear                    #
rails tmp:clear                          # Clear cache, socket and screenshot files from tmp/...
rails tmp:create                         # Creates tmp directories for cache, sockets, and pids
rails tmp:pids:clear                     #
rails tmp:screenshots:clear              #
rails tmp:sockets:clear                  #
rails yarn:install                       # Install all JavaScript dependencies as specified v...
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me on this problem !

Thank you in advance !

Aurèle

Comment: did you get same error with rake command ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @wasipeer ! I just edit my post to give you the exact error with rails and rake.

Comment: give it a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871368/dont-know-how-to-build-task-dbmigrate-w-rails-3-2-0-rc2

Comment: I tried to delete the Gemfile.lock file and run the bundle install command, but that does not change anything, unfortunately

Comment: did you try bundle update?

Comment: yes, I tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens probably due ruby version upgrade.
Try to install the gems again with `bundle install` and then try again.
If don't work you'll need to run as `bundle exec rails db:migrate` for bundle pick the right version of the gems.

**EDIT:** since your are using rvm, make sure you're using the same Ruby versions. Take a look at this https://rvm.io/workflow/projects and make sure you're in the right version.
Hint: Check the Ruby version in the Gemfile, as it could be the source of your problem.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not change anything (bundle install, bundle update, delete Gemfile.lock + bundle install). I have the same error when I run `bundle exec rails db:migrate`